# Print post data inside loop using theme content template

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-template-part

I am writing a plugin where I need to display the post data inside the loop using the theme content template in a page. It will be a similar page to the author profile page that displays a list of posts but with my own wp_query. I am currently using the following code-

```
while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
```

but the problem is this works for some theme and some not. In some theme they don't output anything. Is there any way so I can make it work on all theme or at least maximum theme?

Comment: Every theme is different, - there is no standard way of naming (or even using) a template part. You would be better off using your own markup and default styles, but allow theme authors to override it with hooks & filters.

Comment: Agreed with TheDeadMedic's comment above. Highly depends on how the author of the theme has built it.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic as an answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every theme is different - there is no standard way of naming (or even using) a template part. You would be better off using your own markup and default styles, but allow theme authors to override it with hooks & filters.